# Bora Bora, Here We Come

Tags: etymology, phrases, expressions

Saw this phrase/expression in CIBC advertisement.

The pleased client asked, "should we re-investment or expand", and the bank clerk said, "you can do both", then the old lady in the back happily claimed,

"Bora Bora, Here We Come"

What does this phrase/expression mean/imply? Where is it coming from?

Comment: See [California, Here I Come](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/California,_Here_I_Come).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"X, here we come" or "X, here I come" is a phrase meaning "We are/I am going to X".  It pretends to be addressed to the place itself: Hey, Bora Bora, I'm coming to you!

The important meaning here is that X is usually a *luxurious* place such as you'd visit for holidays or hope to live in after retirement.  What the phrase is getting at is that the speaker is anticipating being rich.  "Soon I'll be able to afford to go to Bora Bora!"

This can also be used for other places that represent success.  "I won our regional tennis tournament.  Wimbledon, here I come!"

Random fact: In the north of England there was a short-lived variant of this phrase on Twitter: "Birmingham/Manchester Town Hall/Wolverhampton Library/etc, I am in you!" Unlike the above, this version was simply announcing that you are somewhere.